# Reducing the execution time of the code using CLANG/LLVM compiler

Tags: llvm, clang

Well... When i was searching for a good compiler I came across clang/LLVM. This compiler gives me same result as other compilers like icc, pgi. But the problem is there are very few tutorials on this compiler... Kindly let me know where can I find the tutorials on the clang compiler.

Note by:
I have compiled my c code using the following flags  `clang -O3 -mfpmath=sse file.c`

Comment: this is second question from you about ways of optimizing (making faster) code. May be you can post the actual code on StackOverflow? Only that part of code which takes a lot of execution time.

Answer (score 8):

Clang (the command line compiler) takes gcc-compatible options, but accepts and ignores a lot of flags that GCC takes (like -mfpmath=sse).  We aim to generate good code out of the box.  There are some flags that allow clang to violate the language standards that can be useful in some scenarios, like -ffast-math though.

If you're looking for good performance, I highly recommend experimenting with link-time-optimization, which allows clang to optimize across source files in your application.  Depending on what platform you're on, this is enabled by passing -O4 to the compiler.  If you're on linux, you need to use the "gold" linker (see http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html).  If you're on the mac, it should "just work" with any recent version of Xcode.

Comment: I can't find a page that list the gcc options that clang actually takes into account (like -ffast-math). Is there a such page?

Comment: @AlexandreHamez The man page lists -ffast-math. I would guess that the man page is authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

The clang is not a compiler, it is just frontend of LLVM compiler. So, when you calls clang, it parses c/c++ file but the optimization and code generation is handled in LLVM itself.

Here you can found a documentation of LLVM optimization and analysis options: http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html

The full documentation is here http://llvm.org/docs/

Also useful options are listed here http://linux.die.net/man/1/llvmc (I suggest clang will accept most of them too)

Comment: I think that Clang simply pass those to the LLVM compiler :)

Comment: @Matthieu M., yes it can pass some. But also (at least theoretically) it can disallow some options and give a error (abort) on them. E.g. clang can abort on `-x` option with not c/c++ lang, but llvmc itself can accept this lang if it have a frontend for it.